# How do you get argparse to choose a default subparser?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code in `script.py`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
sp.default = 'a'

a_parser = sp.add_parser('a')
b_parser = sp.add_parser('b')

a_parser.add_argument('--thing', default='thing')
b_parser.add_argument('--nothing', default='nothing')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

I can call this three different ways:

```
$ python3 script.py
Namespace(command='a')
$ python3 script.py a
Namespace(command='a', thing='thing')
$ python3 script.py b
Namespace(command='b', nothing='nothing')
```

There's only one problem with this: what I *want* is that if I provide zero arguments on the command line is for `a_parser` to be the one that ends out parsing and doing stuff. Clearly it's not, the `sp.default` is just setting `command='a'`, not what I expect, which is to say, "Oh yeah, the user didn't provide any arguments on the command line, but I know that this should be processed by `a_parser`. Here's `Namespace(command='a', thing='thing')`!"

Is there a way that I *can* do this with argparse? I've looked for a few different options, but none of them really seem to provide what I'm after. I guess I could do some jiggery with making 3 distinct ArgumentParsers and then passing on the arguments to each of them, though that sounds a bit gross.

Any better options?

Comment: You could investigate command line frameworks like [cliff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cliff) or [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) that provide generally better support for this sort of design.

Comment: better use docopt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First a historical note - subparsers were not optional, and they still aren't in Python2.  The fact that they are optional in Py3 is something of a bug that was introduced several years ago.  There was a change in the test for required arguments, and subparsers (a kind of positional) fell through the cracks.  If done right you should have had to explicitly set subparsers as not-required.

Subparsers don't behave like other non-required arguments, ones with `nargs='?'` or flagged without the `required` parameter.

In any case, your `sp.default` defines the value that will be put in the `command` dest, but it does not trigger the use of `a_parser`.  That `command='a'` is never 'evaluated'.

The use of `parse_known_args` might allow you to devaluate the remaining strings with `a_parser`.

Without any arguments, we can do:

```
In [159]: args, extras = parser.parse_known_args([])
In [160]: args
Out[160]: Namespace(command='a')
In [161]: extras
Out[161]: []
```

Then conditionally run `a_parser` (if command is 'a' but no 'thing')

```
In [163]: a_parser.parse_args(extras,namespace=args)
Out[163]: Namespace(command='a', thing='thing')
```

But if I try to include a `--thing` value:

```
In [164]: args, extras = parser.parse_known_args('--thing ouch'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] {a,b} ...
ipython3: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'ouch' (choose from 'a', 'b')
```

It tries to parse the 'ouch' as subparser name.  The main parser doesn't known anything about the `--thing` argument.

As I explained in the other `argparse` question today, the toplevel parser parses the inputs until it finds something that fits the 'subparsers' command (or in this example raises an error).  Then it passes the parsing to the subparser.  It does not resume parsing after.

[Add top level argparse arguments after subparser args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962065/add-top-level-argparse-arguments-after-subparser-args)

[How to Set a Default Subparser using Argparse Module with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667843/how-to-set-a-default-subparser-using-argparse-module-with-python-2-7)

My answer to this Py2 request might work for you.  I first run a `parse_known_args` with a parser that doesn't have subparsers, and conditionally run a second parser that handles the subparsers.

```
In [165]: firstp = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [166]: args, extras = firstp.parse_known_args('--thing ouch'.split())
In [167]: args
Out[167]: Namespace()
```

If `extras` doesn't have 'a' or 'b' call `a_parser` (alternatively just look at `sys.argv[1:]` directly):

```
In [168]: extras
Out[168]: ['--thing', 'ouch']
In [169]: a_parser.parse_args(extras)
Out[169]: Namespace(thing='ouch')
```

Or modify `extras` to include the missing subparser command:

```
In [170]: extras = ['a']+extras
In [171]: parser.parse_args(extras)
Out[171]: Namespace(command='a', thing='ouch')
```

In any case, `optional` subparsers is not well developed in `argparse`.  It's the side effect of a change made a while back, rather than a well thought out feature.